Mounting a folder using rclone. Can't see the contents of `/mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/`
I have a Pixel 6a with Android 14, rooted, config SMB. I did everything according to the instructions at How to mount rclone on Android?, but got an error:
~ $ bin/rclone mount.sh
2024/04/02 09:21:03 INFO  : smb://elec@192.168.1.109:445/: poll-interval is not supported by this remote
2024/04/02 09:21:03 Fatal error: failed to mount FUSE
fs: cannot open: /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/GDrive:
open /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/GDrive: no such file or directory



How to solve the problem?
